# JS queue array debug error

Tags: javascript, arrays, debugging

I am receiving this error,

Practice.html:formatted:20 Uncaught TypeError: **queueArray.push is not a function**
    at Queue.add (Practice.html:formatted:20)
    at Practice.html:formatted:30

but push isn't supposed to be a function. It is supposed to be a method executed on an array. So what could this mean??

```
 var tickerArray = ['BP', 'AMZN', 'EARK'];
    //also tried putting queueArray here because that would make it global, so i guess it isnt a scope issue?

    function Queue() {
        this.top = 0; //first item in the stack
        var queueArray = []; //array to hold items
    }

    Queue.prototype.add = function(obj) {
        queueArray.push(obj);
    }

    Queue.prototype.get = function() {
        return queueArray.splice(this.top, 1);
    }


    var queueArray = new Queue();

    for (i = 0; i < tickerArray.length; i++) {
        queueArray.add(tickerArray[i]);
    }

    console.log(q.get());
```

Comment: Cause `queueArray` is `undefined` as its locally scoped inside the constructor

Comment: Yes, I already tried putting it outside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `queueArray` as `this.queueArray` and `return` `this.queueArray` from `.get()`

```js
var tickerArray = ['BP', 'AMZN', 'EARK'];

function Queue() {
  this.top = 0; //first item in the stack
  this.queueArray = []; //array to hold items
}

Queue.prototype.add = function(obj) {
  this.queueArray.push(obj);
}

Queue.prototype.get = function() {
  this.queueArray.splice(this.top, 1);
  return this.queueArray; // `return` `this.queueArray` from the function
}

var queueArray = new Queue();

for (i = 0; i < tickerArray.length; i++) {
  queueArray.add(tickerArray[i]);
}

console.log(queueArray.get());
```

Comment: On a queue i would expect `.get` to return the first element

Comment: @JonasW. If the spliced element is expected `var curr = this.queueArray.splice(this.top, 1); return curr[0]`